# Is AOSP's libc++.so the same as NDK's libc++_shared.so?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I'm working in an Android app in which one shared library (that I build in Android Studio, and let's call it `libA.so`) dynamically loads another shared library provider by a vendor (let's call it `libB.so`). I know that I shouldn't use multiple C++ runtime libraries in my app (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#important_considerations) so we've decided to use c++_shared in both libs.

`libB.so` (the one provided by a vendor) is compiled and linked when AOSP is built (the vendor insists in building the library this way, can't do much about it). The makefile for `libB.so` is setting the STL flag to c++_shared with this:

```
LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT := c++_shared
```

When I look at the NEEDED tag in the `libB.so` library, I can see the dependency to `libc++.so`

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++.so] <----
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libB.so]
```

When I run `readelf -d libc++.so` to check the content of AOSP's libc++.so I get this

```
Dynamic section at offset 0xe4b40 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0xe6310
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           22128 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x39ff8
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x2ce58
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             53664 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          380
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x238
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0xdeb8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              102917 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x270c0
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libc++.so]
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0xe08e0
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0xe5b38
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x2bb7c
 0x000000006ffffffc (VERDEF)             0x2cddc
 0x000000006ffffffd (VERDEFNUM)          1
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x2cdf8
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         2
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

I know the NDK provides also `libc++.so`, but when I run the same command in the library distributed in the Android NDK, I get an error

```
readelf: Error: libc++.so: Failed to read file header
```

And if I'm not mistaken, that's because in the NDK, `libc++.so` is in fact a linker script.

`libA.so` (the one that I build with my app and loads `libB.so`) ends up with a dependency to `libc++_shared.so`

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x4bca50 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++_shared.so] <---
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libA.so]
```

I don't think I can (or should) bundle both `libc++.so` and `libc++_shared.so` in my app.

So, is AOSP's `libc++.so` the same as NDK's `libc++_shared.so`?

Someone knows why AOSP adds a dynamic dependency to `libc++.so` instead of `libc++_shared.so` even when `LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT := c++_shared` is used? Should I ask my provider to link against `libc++_shared.so` instead? Maybe someone has a better recommendation to fix this dependency mismatch.

Comment: "Someone knows why AOSP adds a dynamic dependency to libc++.so instead of libc++_shared.so even when LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT := c++_shared is used?" LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT is ignored if LOCAL_SDK_VERSION is not set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. libc++.so in AOSP is built against the latest  (technically it's the *future* API level) API level and without libandroid_support. It is built with a different set of flags, and is potentially a different ABI. It is built with a set of architecture flags that allow the compiler to use instructions that are not available on all Android devices. It is also a different revision from the one in the NDK, but that is also true of different NDK versions and is less significant in deciding whether or not they are compatible.

If the vendor is providing libB.so to you for inclusion in your app, they are building it incorrectly. As you've noticed, it is linking against the platform libc++.so, which is not accessible to applications. There is no fix from your side; the vendor needs to provide a proper NDK library. If they want to continue using the AOSP build system they need to set `LOCAL_SDK_VERSION` so `LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT` isn't ignored.

If the vendor is providing a device with this library installed to the system image (i.e. /system/lib64/libB.so, *not* included in your application), then the guidance in @alex-cohn's answer applies. This is how official NDK libraries like libandroid.so are built. They link against the system's libc++.so, but only expose a C ABI to applications. As long as the vendor follows these guidelines, this is fine.

As Alex mentions, the document that you quote is slightly more restrictive than the reality of the situation. It *is* possible to use multiple STLs in the same program (otherwise NDK applications wouldn't work at all, since the platform and the application use different STLs), but it does require very careful management of the surface area of your ABIs and a good deal of caution to avoid ODR violations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's OK to mix different C++ runtimes in one app, as long as they do not *interact*. What this means, the C++ objects (including exceptions) should not cross the boundaries of their shared library. Therefore, if your **libB.so** provides an **extern "C"** public API, you can safely use these functions from components compiled for *any* C++ runtime, even **stlport_static**.

If the vendor lib does not export a pure C API, it's a violation of the architecture provisions (see https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/images/vndk_design_android_o.pdf, page 27). In this situation, you may need to build your dependent **libA.so** as part of AOSP, too. You can do that if you choose to couple your library more tightly to **libB.so**, e.g. extend some of its classes, throw exceptions across libA/libB boundary, etc.

Note that since Android N, the system linker [protects](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk) platform libraries (those in /system/lib and /vendor/lib) from being **dlopen**ed from user code. You should consider adding **libB**, or **libA**, or both, to the [whitelist](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/namespaces_libraries#adding-additional-native-libraries).

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#static_runtimes) link from the Android NDK doc says that the runtime behavior of an app that has 2 (or more) shared libraries that were linked against a static runtime library "is undefined, and in practice crashes are very common", but you mentioned that it's OK to use any C++ runtime as long as the C++ objects don't cross boundaries OR if a library provides an extern "C" API.  `libB.so` does provide an extern "C" API, so can the vendor safely link his library against a static C++ library like gnustl_static (and me too)?

Comment: Yes, either side can use any static STL if they prefer. For a vendor lib, it would be more natural to use the shared STL from system/lib because this saves space.

Comment: Correction: I seem to have misguided you. I wanted to say *it's OK to use any C++ runtime as long as the C++ objects don't cross boundaries **AND** the library provides an extern "C" API.*.