# Confustion about Android NDK libc++ libc++_shared, libstdc++

Tags: c++, android-ndk, libc++

I am getting very confused trying to build a simple C++ library using Android NDK 23 (23.1.7779620). I am using CMake and this is a very simple program:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(mf) 
add_library(mf lib.cpp)

// lib.hpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
std::string foo(std::string);

// lib.cpp
#include "lib.hpp"
std::string foo(std::string str) {
  return std::string{"test"} + str;
}
```

This is the command line to build:

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-29  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake .. 
cmake --build . -v
```

- The first problem is that I was expecting to link against `libc++.so` and not `libc++_shared.so`. What is the difference between them? I read [this article](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support). But still is not explained the difference betweend `libc++` and `libc++_shared`
- The second problem is even worst, it seems I am using libstdc++!
- The 3rd point, I was thinking that the c++ implementation of clang was under the namespace `std::__1` but I cannot find anything like that.

I know libc++_shared is used because of this command:

```
$ readelf -d libmf.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x76e0 contains 26 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++_shared.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libmf.so]
```

Running nm it seem I am using symbols from `libstdc++`:

```
$ nm -gDC libmf.so | grep '__ndk1'
0000000000003af0 T foo(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >)
                 U std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)
$ nm -gDC libmf.so | grep '__1'
$
```

**Update**

In this post is explained the difference between `libc++.so` and `libc++_shared.so`

Comment: (1) It isn't clear why you think `libc++_shared.so` is being used. Do you have build logs that suggest it? (2) It isn't clear why you think you are using `libstdc++`. This symbol pattern is not characteristic of `libstdc++`. `__1` is not necessarily present in all installations of `libc++` either. `1` in `__1` is `what _LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION` expands to, but it can be configured to expand to anything.

Comment: These are definitely not symbols from libstdc++. There is an ABI namespace named `__cxx11` in `libstdc++`, but it is (1) hardcoded and (2) does not apply to all symbols, in particular not to `allocator` or `char_traits`.

Comment: So what is the difference between `libc++.so` and `libc++_shared.so`, Why Android ndk doesn't allow "easily" to "just" use `libc++.so`?

Comment: This I don't know.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I've found the reply in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244362/is-aosps-libc-so-the-same-as-ndks-libc-shared-so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing `-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared` to the CMake invocation you explicitly asked for the shared runtime as opposed to the default runtime.

As explained in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#ic), the rules are simple:

1. if *all* your native code is in a single library, use the static libc++ (the default) such that unused code can be removed and you have the smallest possible application package.
2. As soon as you include an extra library – either because you include a precompiled library from somewhere else or you include an Android AAR file that happens to include native code – you *must* switch to the shared runtime.

The rationale for the rules is simple: the C++ runtime has certain global data structures that *must* be initialized once and *must* only exist once in memory. If you were accidentally to load two libraries that both link the C++ runtime statically, you have (for instance) two conflicting memory allocators.
This will result in crashes when you `free` or `delete` memory allocated by the other library, or if you pass a C++ STL object like `std::string` across library boundaries.

For completeness, in older NDKs libstdc++ (the GNU C++ runtime) was also included in the NDK, but as of NDK r18 that is no longer the case.

Comment: I am still confused because on my board the library are linking against `libc++.so` but when I am using the ndk I am linking against `libc++_shared.so`.
This library is not in the target and I need to deploy it as well... Cannot I just link against `libc++.so`? Is there a way?

Comment: The second note on the linked page is very explicit: "Note: libc++ is not a system library. If you use libc++_shared.so, it must be included in your app. If you're building your application with Gradle this is handled automatically." In other words: it doesn't matter what is on your board, the APK will package its own libc++_shared.so

Comment: _"As soon as you include an extra library – either because you include a precompiled library from somewhere else or you include an Android AAR file that happens to include native code – you must switch to the shared runtime"_. Not necessarily. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389560/1524450

Comment: Good remark. I think the Android documentation and I are biased to simple advice that errs on the side of caution.